# How do i get the rest of the digits?

Tags: regex, perl

```
Campus: Fairlane North
Building: testtesttest 5850 Mercury Dr
Floor: Floor 01 Common Area
```

Given the above test I want to extract "5850 Mercury"

I have tried  `/Building:.*(\d+\s\w+)/`

Which gets me 
`0 Mercury`

How do i get the rest of the digits? The number of digits can range from 1 to 6.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can keep your regex and add in a `\b` before the `\d+` so it looks for a word boundary: `/Building:.*(\b\d+\s\w+)/`

Answer (score 5):

Three methods.

1. Use non-greedy matching `.*?` instead of greedy matching `.*`

   ```
   /Building:.*?(\d+\s\w+)/
   ```
2. Impose a word boundary `\b` to ensure you match the full number:

   ```
   /Building:.*(\b\d+\s\w+)/
   ```
3. Change from the any character `.` to non-digits `\D`:

   ```
   /Building:\D*(\d+\s\w+)/
   ```

Comment: +1 for answer that takes the time to teach several aspects of regex syntax. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
\b\d+\s\w+
```

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nW9kX2/2)

Comment: That would also match `01 Common`.

Comment: @Sneftel No, because it only matches the first match

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following.

```
\b(\d{4} \w+)
```

Comment: Not all addresses are exactly 4 digits, you know.